# Delphi XE2 error building a package

Tags: delphi, package, bpl, jedi-code-library

I have a package where a unit uses JCL.

When I try build the package it states

> E2225 Never-build package 'Jcl' must be recompiled

So I load the package Jcl.dproj / Jcl160.bpl file into Delphi and build it. No errors here.

But I still get the same error afterwards?

Any possible reasons? I have checked the file Jcl160.bpl get updated on re-build

Comment: Check if you have any other Jcl160.bpl/dcp files in your library paths?  When you manually compiled it may have placed the compiled libraries in a different location to where the installation of JCL orginally went

Comment: compiler/linker settings may be different, changing package ABI and making it incompatible. However i suggest you start with @Jason's advice and making file access log during compilation of your package (with SysInternals Process Monitor or similar tool) and check if there is no orphaned DCU/DCP files. More so, if you compiled from IDE then there is a 90% chance that you created DCP/DCU files in different folder, than JCL Installer did and registered in IDE Library settings.

Comment: *Jcl160.bpl get updated on re-build* That does not matter at all. Matter only files that are used during compilation - \*.DC\*

Answer (score 2):

Had the same error a while ago.  Check your system if older versions of the jcl package/bpl is somewhere present.  Clean those up and the problem will most likely be gone...

Comment: I agree with Copilot, this error is most likely due to the bpl existing in another place on your disk to where you think it is, use agentransack to search for files.